# Need help on Polynomial Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

# Load the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('winequality-red.csv')

# Extracting features and target variable
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)

# Creating polynomial features
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree=5)  
X_poly_train = poly_reg.fit_transform(X_train)
X_poly_test = poly_reg.transform(X_test) 

# Fitting Linear Regression to the dataset
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_poly_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_poly_test)

# Printing the predicted values and actual values
print(np.concatenate((y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred),1), y_test.reshape(len(y_test),1)),1))
```

I want to print the predicted values of the dependent variable vs the actual values of y.
I know there is something like inverse transform that needs to be applied but I am unable to find any such method.
This is the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/red-wine-quality-cortez-et-al-2009/data

Comment: Isn't the last line of your code doing what you want? What is it doing instead, how is that different of what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your print statement at the end of your code is meant to display the predicted values alongside the actual values.

If you want a better visual of the values you can make a data frame. You get a result like [image]

All you need is to modify the end of your code as follows:

```
# Printing the predicted values and actual values
results = np.concatenate((y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred),1), y_test.reshape(len(y_test),1)),1)
print(pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Predicted', 'Actual']))
```

Comment: thanks @shamiso. I was under the impression that the polynomial features somehow is scaling the features to a different scale and I need to scale them back. I got confused by looking at the negative values.